# Any neat ways to get info of different binary files with the same source code

Tags: linux, apt, package-management, distributions

I'm planning to collect different executable files with the same source code in all Linux distros and all architectures, as much as possible, and for scientific purposes only.

I'm now collecting package infos in each distro and version (e.g. Ubuntu 18.04 and Debian 12, and Debian's package is like 'http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/dists/bookworm/main/binary-all/Packages.gz'), then find out the concatenation and intersection of packages of all systems by package names and MD5 of the executable file, then compare the source code of each package.

My point is that the above method might work, but it is too cumbersome. I'd like to know if there is a more delicate way to do that, maybe a website collects some related information or something else.
I have looked into repology.org and pkgs.org, pkgs.org is great, but it limited API request times though.